# Path around bitmap image's visible part?

Tags: inkscape

I found this tool a while back but can't seem to remember how it's done. Basically, I remember there being a tool in Inkscape where you select a bitmap image that has transparency, and it will create a path around the visible part of the image. I know for certain it's not in the Trace Bitmap option, but I can't remember where it is. I also remember the smoothness of the path being relative to how zoomed in/out you were for some reason. Here's an example of what it outputs:

[image: two examples of what the output looks like]

Comment: What is the end goal that you want to achieve with this? Maybe you  want to add additional stroke around the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the bucket fill tool. Set the threshold level to something high, say 10 or above to smoothen the trace.[image]

Comment: You, my good sir or madam, have found that mystery tool I've been searching for (and it was in an obvious spot too)! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a a specific tool but you could accomplish this by:
Trace Bitmap at a setting that makes everything one color. Now you have a shape that matches the non-transparent portion of the bmp. Set that shape to no fill with a colored stroke.